# PHP submitting form data with returned values

Tags: arrays, forms, post

I am using php to create a form which submits product details to a mysql db. I want users to be able to edit the products details. I have called the details of the product from the db and returned them in a form (as below). However, when I try to submit the array I cannot see the values or keys My aim is to resubmit the data, if updated, overwriting the existing information and save it to the database. I do have another submit button on the page for uploading images, but not sure if this is causing the problem. Help would be appreciated...

```
$newProd->getLineForm($returnId);
foreach($newProd->getLineForm($returnId) as $item => $val){ 
?>

<form id="newLineForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"    enctype="multipart/form-data">     

<div class="well">
<ul>
<h3>Step 1</h3>
<br />
<table>
<td><label>Product Code</label><input type="text" style="width:100px;" name="int_prod_code" value="<?php echo $val['int_prod_code']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><label>Nationality</label><input type="text" style="width:100px;" name="nationality" value="<?php echo $val['nationality']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><label>Product Description</label><input type="text" style="width:350px;" name="prod_desc" value="<?php echo $val['prod_desc']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><label>Raw Material</label><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="raw_material" value="<?php echo $val['raw_material']; ?>"></input></td>
</table>

<br />

<span class="btn btn-update fileinput-button">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
<span>Update</span>
<input type="submit" name="update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting it via GET. I was having an issue where I wasn't sending my form to the proper page and thus POST wasn't working even though GET was. If GET is working you'll at least be able to narrow down that your form is being submitted, then will be able to troubleshoot as to why POST isn't working properly.

Comment: Ok, I changed the form to GET and the values were passed in the url string. When I try to print the array using print_r($_GET['update']); nothing is returned. Can you explain this to me?